# Is there a built-in function to get a number when i have numbers and their probabilities? (Python)

Tags: python, probability

I have a dictionary where keys are the numbers and values are probabilities. Is there any (built-in) way to return a number? Basically, I want an analog of randrange() with custom probabilities. Use of dictionary is not necessary.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to choose a random key from the dict, and the return the probability associated with that?

Comment: No, I want to choose one of the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
d = {10:0.5, 9: 0.4, 8:0.1}
x,p = zip(*d.items())
np.random.choice(x, p=p)
```